# scroll to bottom of div after refreshing

Tags: php, html, ajax, load, refresh

I've got some basic ajax to load new messages in my chat, and I have it set to refresh the div with .load, and scroll to bottom with scroll height... only problem is, .load is forcing the div to top, while scrollheight is forcing to bottom, so my chat is just bouncing up and down. I've tried everything I can think to fix this, but nothing is working.

```
<script>
setInterval("scroll();",1000); 
function scroll(){
var element = document.getElementById("chit");
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
    $('#hat').load(location.href + ' #chit');
}
</script>




<?php   if(isset($_GET['user'])){ global $con;
    $get_id = $_GET['user'];
    $get_user = "select * from users where user_name='$get_id'";
    $run_user = mysqli_query($con,$get_user);
    $row_user = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);
    $user2 = $row_user['user_name'];
    }
?>
<main role="main" id="chat" align="center">
<div id="chat_tit" align="center"><?php echo $user2 ; ?></div>
<div id="hat">
<div id="chit" align="left">

<?php 
$c_hat = "SELECT * FROM msg WHERE (user_to='$user' AND user_from='$user2') OR (user_from='$user' AND user_to='$user2')";
$run_chat = mysqli_query($con,$c_hat);

            while($chat=mysqli_fetch_array($run_chat)){
                $from = $chat['user_from'];
                $msg = $chat['msg_body'];
                $time = ago($chat['date']);

echo '<div id="chat_box"><div id="from">[<a href="pfp.php?user_name='.$from.'">'.$from.'</a>]</div><div id="time">'.$time.'</div><div id="msg">'.$msg.'</div>

<div id="underline"></div>

</div>';



}
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `setInterval()` when you may need to use `setTimeout()`. `setInterval()` is being called every second so this could be why it is jumping. `setTimeout()` would only be called once.